# No HTML Markup Visible of WebGrid asynchronously loaded using jQuery and Ajax - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am successfully using jQuery and Ajax on my MVC app to asynchronously load a WebGrid based on a selected item of a DropDownList. I can see the WebGrid and its contents on the view. However, if I then attempt to look at Page Source (to see the HTML markup of the WebGrid), the bit inside the div tags for the WebGrid is empty. So I have:

```
<div id="gridContent">
   //completely empty
</div>
```

Why is this empty? The WebGrid is perfectly visible. Many thanks

Comment: How have you tried to look at page source. because if you looked it by "View page source" you can't see dynamically added content. you can use "inspect element" for it

Comment: Yes, View Page Source. I guess you answered my question nicely. I will not be able to see it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Inspect Element" command instated of "View Page Source"